# How to align VS code terminal in bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you see the terminal is in left side but i want to align it to the bottom of the vs code. how to do that please help me.

[image]

Comment: See the duplicate generally.  If you just want it under the editor, use `center` instead of `justify`  for the Panel alignment.

Comment: i dont satisfy with your answer

Comment: Those are the only possibilities - where exactly do you wan the terminal?  You say "the bottom of vs code" - be more specific.